# Build llvm-ar statically

Tags: cmake, llvm

I'm trying to compile `llvm-ar` (and only that) from LLVM statically because I need a static ar implementation for another purpose. AFAICS the official LLVM building documentation doesn't discuss this usage, only the option to build with shared libs, which is disabled by default anyway. Adding `-static` to CLAGS or the CMake option LLVM CFLAGS doesn't change the build process at all.

This is the build process I'm running right now:

```sh
cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=llvm-ar -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm
make -j3 llvm-ar
```

which then builds a dynamic llvm-ar:

```
$ ldd bin/llvm-ar
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff46154000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007faa84536000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007faa84319000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007faa840ef000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007faa83d66000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007faa839c8000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007faa837b0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007faa833bf000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007faa87163000)
```

How can I cause this target to be compiled statically? I'd also like to build with `musl-gcc` instead of the system default.

Comment: Make sure the environment variable `LIBRARY_PATH` includes the libraries you want used, and not the ones you don't.